# Flutter FutureBuilder returns nothing - Cloud Firestore and Deserialization

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, deserialization

I have the following problem. I'm trying to receive data from my Firestore collection called *tournaments*. I'm querying the database from within my DatabaseService class. That looks like the following:

```
class Collection<T> {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;

  Collection({this.path}) {
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }

  Future<List<Tournament>> getData() async {
    var snapshots = await ref.getDocuments();
    return snapshots.documents
        .map((doc) => Global.models[Tournament](doc.data))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

The widget implements a FutureBuilder

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Global.tournamentRef.getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          List<Tournament> tournaments = snap.data;
...
```

I want to deserialize the firestore data into a Tournament object. I defined the Tournament class as this:

```
class Tournament {
  String id;
  String name;
  String mode;
  String owner;
  int size;

  Tournament({this.id, this.name, this.mode, this.owner, this.size});

  factory Tournament.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Tournament(
        id: data["id"] ?? '',
        mode: data["mode"] ?? '',
        name: data["name"] ?? "group",
        owner: data["owner"] ?? "",
        size: data["size"] ?? 6);
  }
}
```

The last class that is important is the globals.dart

```
class Global {

  static final Map models = {Tournament: (data) => Tournament.fromMap(data)};

  static final Collection<Tournament> tournamentRef =
      Collection<Tournament>(path: "tournaments");
}
```

It simply specifies the collection path. I want the data to be deserialized but I don't have a clue why it isn't returning anything. I've tried querying the database in a simple old-fashioned way like

```
Future<dynamic> retrieveData() async {
    var querySnap = await ref.getDocuments();

    var list = querySnap.documents.map((snap) => snap.data);

    return list;
  }
```

That worked perfectly fine, however it doesn't help with deserialization at all. I think i missed something at some point and as you may notice I'm still a Flutter/dart beginner and some of these discussed topics are a bit too complicated to me.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you